# C# if condition isn't true do something

Tags: c#

my code:

```
string[] code = new string[9];
int[] intCode = new int[9];

int cd = 0, dvd = 0, video = 0, book = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{

    Console.Write("Enter code#{0}: ",i+1);
    code[i] = Console.ReadLine();
    if (code[i].Length==5)
    {
        intCode[i] = Convert.ToInt32(code[i]);
        intCode[i] /= 100000;
        if (intCode[i] == 1)
        {
            cd++;
            break;

        }
        if (intCode[i] == 2)
        {
            dvd++;
            break;
        }
        if (intCode[i] == 3)
        {
            video++;
            break;
        }
        if (intCode[i] == 4)
        {
            book++;
            break;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("INVALID CODE");

    }

}
```

Basically what i want to do is else{do some thing here} to ask the user to reinput the number, instead of going to for loop and icrementing i and asking the user for new input.

Comment: you've heard of the "not" condition right? it looks like you have logic failure in your code.  think more how you as a person would work this out and try and write it down to explain to someone who wouldnt know

Comment: Or a `while` loop perhaps? It's hard to tell what you're looking for here...

Comment: You're dividing a 5 digit number by a 6 digit number, and expecting the result to be 1, 2, 3 or 4. If I were you I'd just check `if (code[i][0] == '1')` etc. instead.

Comment: dividing by a 6 digit number was a mistake, Well i am a newbie :) not a genius :)

Comment: @DanialAhmed happens to me every day :P

Comment: Yay, Jon Skeet edited your code. Hurrah...

Comment: Your program is full of potential land mines, there are so many points which can lead to an error, like you enter string, then do `Convert.ToInt32(code[i])`, which for most of the cases would be sure shot exception when its not able to convert. Use `int.TryParse` instead

Comment: @MrinalKamboj yeah :P thats why i am now using C.Evenhuis's idea :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the else block:

```
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("INVALID CODE");
    i -= 1;
}
```

Comment: I just guess you want to user to reinput it, so just do i again, then it is good.

Comment: Good Tweak, will help the OP

Answer (score 0):

Use a combination of while and switch:

```
        string[] code = new string[9];
        int[] intCode = new int[9];
        int cd = 0, dvd = 0, video = 0, book = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            bool isCorrectInput = false;
            while (!isCorrectInput)
            {
                isCorrectInput = true;
                Console.Write("Enter code#{0}: ", i+1);
                code[i] = Console.ReadLine();
                if (code[i].Length == 1)
                {
                    intCode[i] = Convert.ToInt32(code[i]);
                    // intCode  /= 100000;
                    switch (intCode[i])
                    {
                        case 1:
                            cd++;
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            dvd++;
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            video++;
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            book++;
                            break;
                        default:
                            isCorrectInput = false;
                            break;
                    }
                }
                else
                    isCorrectInput = false;
                if (!isCorrectInput)
                    Console.WriteLine("INVALID CODE ENTERED!");
            }
        }
```

EDIT: 
Should be what you want now, also corrected your bugs

Comment: Doesnt work. It says invalid input even when the input is valid

Comment: You were asking for a way to let the user reinput the number, here it is, the problem that your input cannot be valid is, because you are checking the length for equal to 5 and then divide by 100000, each 5 digit value if divided by 100000 and parsed to int will be 0, and 0 is not handled in your scenario so it's impossible to be correct